# How can I base one CSS setting on another?

Tags: css

Given the following dynamically generated CSS:

```
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #4297d7; background: #5c9ccc; }
```

How can I extract the `background` value for use in:

```
body
{
background-color: VALUE_FROM_UI_WIDGET_HEADER_GOES_HERE;
}
```

More details: I use [jQuery-UI Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and let users upload their own themes.  I'd like the page's background color to be based on a color from Themeroller.  This lets them customize the background color.  Can this be done only in CSS?

Comment: hmm, I don't think it is possible to retrieve the background color with css. It is definitely possible in Javascript. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think it might be possible with formulas but you dont want too many of those in your css because they are run every time you move the mouse over your page, and too many can really slow your page's response time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to define relationships in CSS only.

You'd have to use javascript to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I think you were first.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way, in CSS, to say "The value of this property should be the same as the value of a property in another rule-set".

For this sort of thing, you would generally use a grouping selector:

```
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #4297d7; }

.ui-widget-header,
body {
    background: #5c9ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "There is no way" answers are correct afaik --  The best you can get is using a CSS framework (or maybe more accurately "compiler") such as [Compass](http://wiki.github.com/chriseppstein/compass) that will permit you to define variables, subclasses, and similar in source files that are then compiled to the live CSS.  There's a [nice roundup of CSS compilers here](http://blog.davidziegler.net/post/92203003/css-compilers-rock).

Comment: I would argue this is different than what @Bob asks for, as any CSS framework are essentially relying on the whatever language to generates the CSS to achieve universal control, which is different from retrieve value with pure css without other languages.

Comment: I had never heard of CSS compilers.  I'm so glad you brought them to my attention.  Thanks.